# Is it possible to make labels of columns in QTableView editable?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been learning QAbstractTabelModel with QTabelView. I was able to use Flags, and setData in order to make items editable. However, I have no idea how to make columns editable. In other words, I want to change the names of columns by double-clicking and giving a new name. If it is possible can you give some examples + comments on code?
Here I have a simple application using QTabelView which displays some data using a model.

I would appreciate any suggestion

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[[]], headers=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)


        self.__data = data
        self.__headers = headers

    # Headers
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:


                if section < len(self.__headers):
                    return self.__headers[section]
                else:
                    return "Temporary"

            else:
                return section + 1


    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])


    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            return self.__data[row][column]

        # Displaying data
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value


    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    # Making cells editable==================================
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            new_element = value
            if new_element:
                self.__data[row][column] = new_element
                return True

            else:
                return False

        # =============================================================================#
        # INSERTING & REMOVING  ITEMS

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):

        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for i in range(rows):
            defaultValues = [i for i in range(1, 4)]
            self.__data.insert(position, defaultValues)

        self.endInsertRows()
        return True


    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)  # Старт процесс удаления
        # Removing here
        for i in range(rows):
            value = self.__data[position]
            self.__data.remove(value)

        self.endRemoveRows()

        return True


    def insertColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)
        """self.beginInsertColumns(index, first, last)"""
            # index - parent
        # first - position
        # last - position + columns - 1 = view ожидает 0 образный элемент

        rowCount = len(self.__data)
        for i in range(columns):

            for j in range(rowCount):  # Преребираем Строки
                self.__data[j].insert(position, "new cell")

        self.endInsertColumns()
        return True
    # removing columns from view ================================================================
    def removeColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)  # Старт процесс удаления
        # Removing here

        rowCount = len(self.__data)

        for i in range(columns):
            for j in range(rowCount):
                print(self.__data[j])
                value = self.__data[j][position]

                self.__data[j].remove(value)

        self.endRemoveColumns()

        return True


#  My Window -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        data = [
            ["value", "value", "value"],
            ["value", "value", "value"]
        ]

        headers = ["col1", "col2", "col3", ]



        self.TableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.TableView.show()


        self.model = MyTableModel(data, headers)

            #inserting rows
        #self.model.insertRows(0, 1)


        # self.model.removeRows(0, 1)

        #self.model.insertColumns(0, 1)


        #self.model.removeColumns(0, 1)
        self.TableView.setModel(self.model)





app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MyWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "make columns editable"? Are you referring to the horizontal header?

Comment: yes exactly to the horizontal header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change single *header* data by means of [`setHeaderData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setHeaderData).

Then simply connect to the [`sectionDoubleClicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionDoubleClicked) signal and use an input dialog to get the new title from the user.

Since you're using a subclass of QAbstractItemModel, you have to overwrite the corresponding method too.

```
class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...

    def setHeaderData(self, section, orientation, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if 0 < section < len(self.__headers) and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            self.__headers[section] = value
            return True
        return QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.setHeaderData(self, section,
            orientation, value, role)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.TableView.horizontalHeader().sectionDoubleClicked.connect(self.renameSection)


    def renameSection(self, index):
        oldTitle = self.model.headerData(
            index, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        newTitle, accepted = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            self, 'Change column title', oldTitle)

        if accepted and oldTitle != newTitle:
            self.model.setHeaderData(
                index, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, newTitle, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
```

Comment: @bejandor don't post code in comments, as it's not correctly formatted. What is the problem? Does the program run? What happens?

Comment: I implemented the code you provided. There is no error after renaming and clicking enter but it does not change the title somehow

Comment: @bejandor I didn't see the update about the custom model, you didn't specify it at the beginning. You have to implement `setHeaderData()`, see my edit. Also, you shouldn't use lists as default values for keyword arguments.

Comment: Wow! that was so kind of you, and it works perfectly! Thanks again!